# Illegal utf8 string in constant pool when loading jawin

Tags: java, class, jar, jawin

I'm trying to load dynamically the class org.jawin.FuncPtr
Jawin: http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/
Unfortunately I'm getting this error:
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file org/jawin/FuncPtr

I'm using this class:

```
/*
 * HelloDll.java -
 *
 * This file is part of the Jawin Project: http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/
 * 
 * Please consult the LICENSE file in the project root directory,
 * or at the project site before using this software.
 */

/* $Id: HelloDll.java,v 1.3 2004/06/14 20:16:38 arosii_moa Exp $ */

package demos;

import org.jawin.COMException;
import org.jawin.FuncPtr;
import org.jawin.ReturnFlags;

/**
 * Demo that uses the Win32 MessageBoxW API-method.
 *
 * @version     $Revision: 1.3 $
 * @author      Stuart Halloway, http://www.relevancellc.com/halloway/weblog/
 */
public class HelloDll {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FuncPtr msgBox = null;
        try {
            msgBox = new FuncPtr("USER32.DLL", "MessageBoxW");
            msgBox.invoke_I(0, "Hello From a DLL", "From Jawin", 0, ReturnFlags.CHECK_FALSE);
        } catch (COMException e) {
            // handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (msgBox != null) {
                try {
                    msgBox.close();
                } catch (COMException e) {
                    // handle fatal exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/ghosertTest/TestProject/blob/master/java-workspace/TestJawin/src/demos/HelloDll.java

I'm loading it dynamically with defineClass.
If I change the HelloDll class to not use Jawin, but just printing "Hello World" for example, no errors are thrown and the code runs fluently, so I assume there isn't any problem with the class loader[?]

How can I figure out why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I am not sure what needs to be figured here. For some reason, the corresponding class file contains some invalid data. Did you compile these classes yourself; or are you using a pre-compiled JAR?

Comment: I'm using a precompiled JAR.

Comment: Well, then I suggest: try to build the whole library on your own and avoid using that JAR. Of course, that does not answer how that "bad" class file in your JAR got created in the first place. Not very likely, but maybe the JAR file got (minimally) corrupted during download?

Comment: When I don't try to load dynamically a class that uses that JAR, but running it directly through java.exe, it does work.

Comment: Well, then lets step back: what do you mean by "dynamically" loading a class from that JAR? Using reflection? Please add the corresponding code to your question.

Comment: I'm using the dynamic class loading in Java, using loadClass, defineClass, etc...

Comment: Coming back to your statement from just before: you mean when you are using the same class from the JAR; but you dont use reflection to access the class, it works?

Comment: Yes, when I'm running HelloDll class with java.exe, it does work.

Comment: A guess would be that the bytes of the .class file are loaded wrong. Better show/inspect that code.